# Guessing Game where user selects max value

Tags: c#, linq, oop, random

I have been tasked in my class to create a random number generating guessing game using c# and do/while, if/else loops. This task seems easy enough; however, I am running into problems because I am supposed to start the game by prompting the user to "Enter a max value you want to guess from".
I cannot get my program to work properly, as every time I run it, no matter what value I enter it says to "select a value between 1 and 0"

I have attached my exe.

```
        Random generator = new Random();
        bool truth = true;
        int MaxRange = Convert.ToInt32(truth); ;
        int userguess = 0;
        int outputnumber = generator.Next(MaxRange);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Enter a max number you want to guess from!", MaxRange);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("please make a guess between 1 and {0}", outputnumber);

            if (userguess != outputnumber)
            {
                userguess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

                if (userguess < outputnumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not correct, Guess again");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if(userguess > outputnumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not correct, Guess again");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (userguess == outputnumber)
                {
 console.writeline("That is correct, the number is {0}, outputnumber);
                }
            }
        } while (truth == false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you don't have that code within any sort of `if` block.. It will print every time.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind..but I don't see anywhere you set `truth` to `false`.  Let me get my other glasses

Comment: I don't see you setting the max number from users response. I am not sure how you are converting a bool to an int for max range. I recommend TryParse on both the maxrange and the guess the user makes to make sure they entered an int.

Comment: How about using a debugger and learn how to use it? Stepping through your code and inspecting variables is usually _much_ easier than asking on SO.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, `Console.ReadLine()` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx))returns a string, which is what the user has typed. You're not actually every trying to get the value from this, so the guesses and the max value aren't ever being modified.  You need something like `userguess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` (and also handle the case where the user types a non integer, but that's a different topic).  In general if you're using C#, MSDN is you friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of errors in your code, but I'll go over the main ones I see by writing comments next to them.

```
Random generator = new Random();
bool truth = true;

//extra semicolon on next line, 
//doesn't make sense to convert a boolean to get your initial max range,
//just give it an initial value, perhaps 0
int MaxRange = Convert.ToInt32(truth); ;
int userguess = 0;

//the generator can't get the correct outputnumber yet because MaxRange hasn't
//been set by the user's input yet
int outputnumber = generator.Next(MaxRange);

do
{
    //this won't get the user input because the parameters in WriteLine() 
    //that come after the string are for inserting into the string, not recieving input
    Console.WriteLine(" Enter a max number you want to guess from!", MaxRange);

    //need to set Console.ReadLine() to a variable for it to be saved
    //should be MaxRange = Console.ReadLine(); (though that will throw an error if the user inputs anything except numbers)
    Console.ReadLine();

    //outputnumber hasn't been set to a true generated number yet
    Console.WriteLine("please make a guess between 1 and {0}", outputnumber);

    //outputnumber could be renamed to be more clear, I would suggest randomNumber
    //userguess is still 0 during the first loop, need to get the user's guess before comparing to the random number
    //also, could simplify these if/else statements to just a couple of them
    //you're also going to need a while loop somewhere in here to continue having the user
    //guess until they get it right
    if (userguess != outputnumber)
    {
        //should use Console.ReadLine()
        userguess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

        if (userguess < outputnumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not correct, Guess again");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if(userguess > outputnumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not correct, Guess again");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (userguess == outputnumber)
        {
//not indented correctly, missing correct capitalization and missing the right quotes on the string to be wrote
console.writeline("That is correct, the number is {0}, outputnumber);
        }
    }
//should just be while (true);
} while (truth == false);
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Being new to development can be overwhelming and it is clear you have not completely thought through the problem and your solution. When developing a new algorithm sometimes it helps to comment the steps you would use and then start developing. They can be vague guidance or more detailed steps but you will find this to be a helpful practice especially when working on complex problems.

Here is an example you can use to rewrite your code and try again. I would also recommend using an int.TryParse() instead of convert.

```
// loop 1
// get users expected max range
//   if not int
//      display message about invalid input
//   if int
//      break loop 1 to start guessing
// end loop 1
// generate random number for user to guess
// loop 2
// prompt user for their guess
// parse input and verify int
//   if not int
//      display message about invalid input
//      continue loop 2 skipping eval code to reprompt for input
// evaluate their guess
//   if matches
//      show success message
//      break loop 2
//   else
//      show failure message
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this.

You are generating a number using 'truth' as the maximum value instead of generating the number after you take input from the user.

You also need to set truth to false after the get the right number.

You probably also want them to have multiple guesses on the same number so you need to move the input for the max range above the start of the 'do'

Take the time to read through your code line by line and think about how variable will be set at different points etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I did some minor adjustments and I almost have it perfect now. The only error I still get is when running it sucessfully, user is asked if they want to play again. If they say yes the game makes them play from the previous Max value selected, not to enter a new one.

namespace Trythisagain
{
    class Program
    {

```
    public static int SelectedNumber = 0;
    public static Random ran = new Random();
    public static bool GameOver = false;
    public static int UserMaxValue = 0;



    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        int UserNumber;
        SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);

        do
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Enter a max number you want to guess from!");
            UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        do
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Select a number between 1 and {0}!", UserMaxValue);
                UserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                GuessNumber(UserNumber);

        } while (GameOver == false);
        } while (GameOver == false);

    }




    public static void GuessNumber(int UserNumber)

    {

        int playagain = 0;

        if (UserNumber < SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Your Number is Wrong! Please try Again!");
        else if (UserNumber > SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Your Number is Wrong! Please Try Again!");
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Yay! You got the right number! Press 1 to play again press 2 to quit");
            playagain = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (playagain != 1 && playagain != 2)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Only Select 1 to play again or 2 to quit!");
                playagain = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            if (playagain.Equals(2))
                GameOver = true;

            else
                SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Upon further inspection it also seems that the random value is often 0 which is shouldn't be allowed to be. Also it seems when you play again the Max Value you enter is usually the "random number" you need to guess from